# swift method's name has been changed in javascript

Tags: swift

when I expose a method goToInternet(url:String) in swift to javascript, it becomes to goToInternetWithUrl in javascript. Does anyone know why? How to avoid the renaming?
My code is in    https://github.com/289977150/CallSwiftFromJS/blob/master/CallSwiftFromJS/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at http://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/#3)-javascript-data-&-processing you can see this note:

> Note: JavaScriptCore translates Objective-C/Swift method names to be
>   JavaScript-compatible. Since JavaScript doesn’t have named parameters,
>   any external parameter names are converted to camel-case and appended
>   to the function name. In this example, the Objective-C method
>   createWithFirstName:lastName: becomes createWithFirstNameLastName() in
>   JavaScript.

The function `func goToInternet(url:String)` has a named parameter `url`.

You can add an underscore to make the parameter have no external name:

`func goToInternet(_ url: String)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try